# Finding smallest prime factor

Tags: ruby, primes

I am trying to create a function that returns the smallest prime factor of a given number:

```
require 'prime'

def findSmallestPrimeFactor(number)
  return 2 if number.even?
  return number if Prime.prime? number
  arrayOfFactors = (1..number).collect { |n| n if number % n == 0 }.compact
  arrayOfFactors.each { |n| arrayOfFactors.pop(n) unless Prime.prime? n }
  return arrayOfFactors[0]
end
```

`findSmallestPrimeFactor(13333)` should return `67` but instead returns `1`, which should not be happening since `1` should be removed from `arrayOfFactors` during line 7, as `Prime.prime? 1` returns `false`

It sometimes returns nothing:

```
puts findSmallestPrimeFactor(13335) # => returns empty line
```

This issue only occurs when working with a number that is not even and is not prime, i.e lines 4 and 5 are ignored.

Also, when this is finished I will be passing some very large numbers through it. Is there any shorter or more efficient way to do lines 6-8 for larger numbers?

Comment: It becomes tricky when you modify an array during iteration. In most cases, you get an unintended result, and that is the case with you. Furthermore, `pop` removes an element at the end, and has nothing to do with the element you are iterating at the moment.

Comment: I am aware of this. Is there a way to do the same thing without modifying the array?

Comment: Clearly state examples and your expected results rather than presenting code that even you by yourself know that is broken.

Comment: I would try something like: going in a loop from 2 till the number and return the number when it is prime and `arg % n == 0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using the `prime` library, it has a [`prime_division`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/prime/rdoc/Integer.html#method-i-prime_division) method:

```
require 'prime'

13335.prime_division
# => [[3, 1], [5, 1], [7, 1], [127, 1]]
13335.prime_division[0][0]
# => 3
```

Comment: Haha, thanks! I did try this using `Prime.prime_division n` but for some reason that wasn't working. This works, though.

Answer (score 1):

If Prime.prime? is false for 1, it will fail the "if" and keeps going.  Try making your array go from 3..sqrt(number)... which will exclude 1, and you've already established the number is odd, so leave out 2 too, and of course there's no need to look at anything higher than the square root either; (because factors always come in pairs a*b=n where a and b are factors; in the case of the square root, a = b... in all other cases, one is less than, and the other greater than, the square root).

Also, rather than gathering the entire collection, consider a regular loop that short circuits the instant it finds a prime factor: why find all factors if all you want is the smallest; (e.g. for 3333, you can quickly find out the smallest prime factor is 3, but would do a lot more steps to find all factors).

Comment: "of course there's no need to look at anything higher than the square root either." I keep hearing this as if it's the most obvious thing in the world, but I don't get it. Can you explain why I don't have to check anything over the square root?

Comment: I modified the answer to explain.